# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php Laravel

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, routes

I have problem to save name and email from user1 in table user1s that I have made .

When I enter them in **textareas** using html form in Laravel with `route::post` and function store it is not working. When I enter text and hit the button Register it outputs the following error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line

You will see that I  use the HTML form and that I have tried to add `<input ....>` into my form.

---

Here are my files:

**route.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/','PageController@home');
Route::post('/','User1Controller@store');

Route::get('about','PageController@about');
```

**welcome.blade.php**

I'm not sure about the `action`.
After putting user1 inf into table, it should be  **redirected to a "Thank you" page** (I have a **thankyou.blade.php** ) , maybe that is the problem

```
<form  method="POST" action=""> 
                    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

                <ul class="list-group" >


                    <li  >
                    NAme
                    <div class="form-group" title="email" >
                        <textarea name="name" class="form-control" >

                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    </li  >

                    <li>Email
                    <div class="form-group" > 
                        <textarea name="email"  class="form-control" >

                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    </li>

                    <li  >
                        <div class="form-group" >
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </form>
```

**migration for user1**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateNotesTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('card_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('body');            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('notes');
    }
}
```

**user1controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User1;

class User1Controller extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
        {

            $user= new User1;
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->email =  $request->email;
            $user->save();

            return view('thankyou');

        }

}
```

**pagecontroller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\User1;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
            $user1s= User1::all();
    return view('welcome',compact('user1s'));
    }

    public function about()
    {
            return view('pages.about'); 
    }

}
```

Comment: `acction="/user1"` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what should  I put as action , I tough that this would mean  that I wisit the page '/user1' after the metod store is finished ,but I'm confused.

Comment: I changed the action=" " .

Comment: `<form  method="POST" acction=""> ` what is `acction`, you mean `action`?

Comment: I corrected the typo.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is basically a registration form. I would recommend using a more meaningful name for the end point. The post route can be something like,

```
Route::post('/register','User1Controller@store');
```

Now the form action can be,

```
action="/register"
```

Comment: what is `acction`?

Comment: Corrected typo (acction to action). I mean action attribute of HTML form tag.

Comment: I corrected the typo.Thanks!  I have also changed this
Route::post('/','User1Controller@store');

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the typo.Thanks!

I have also changed this
Route::post('/','User1Controller@store'); 
and action=" " .

It works ,the only thing right now that is not good is that I should redirect to a page "Thank you" not go to anther view on the exact same page.

Because  It makes a mess in the database when I reload the home page.
 I'll try that and tell if it works.

Thank you people for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Things solved,this works.** I will add the code that i have added so the other can find it!

Firs of all : I **haven't figured why ,but action="dir1/dir3" for me didn't work!**

Here are the added things!

```html
routes.php

Route::get('thankyou','PageController@thankyou');


***PageController.php***


 public function thankyou()
 {
   return view('thankyou'); 
 }

*****User1Controller.php*****

    public function store(Request $request)
     {
      
      $user= new User1;
      $user->name = $request->name;
      $user->email =  $request->email;
      $user->save();

      return redirect('/thankyou');
   
     }
```